# Getting package not found error

Tags: ros, catkin-package, rosrun, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed and have started learning about ROS

I was doing the Publisher/Subscriber tutorial given on the website

I created a package using `catkin_create_package`, built it using `catkin_make` then tried running `rosrun`

there it gives `Package not found` error.

Even `rospack` gives same error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199940/getting-package-not-found-error/) by [udiboy1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/21210/udiboy1209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you remembered to first run `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` ([Examining the Simple Publisher and Subscriber - Running the Publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber))? Excerpt from that page:

> [..] If you are using catkin, make sure you have sourced your workspace's setup.sh file after calling catkin_make but before trying to use your applications:

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [udiboy1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/21210/udiboy1209/) on 2014-12-22**:
Stupid of me! Thanks :)

**Comment by [spkadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/44549/spkadam/) on 2019-08-05**:
Got it.Thanks!

**Comment by [Caloy](https://answers.ros.org/users/72823/caloy/) on 2021-04-02**:
Work for me here also. Unable to follow this instruction since I'm following from a book and not the ros.org tutorial.